# Limiting VRAM available to a process

Tags: windows-7, memory, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-settings

Is it possible to limit the video memory a software can use? In my case, I want to tell a game I have half the memory to test some performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. Some games have command line switches to restrict memory usage, you might want to investigate that.

Answer (score 1):

Some video cards share the RAM as the VRAM, and you can adjust the size in the BIOS.